Quarkus-kubernetes ingress : how to change path-type?
With quarkus-kubernetes, I want to generate an ingress like this :
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    app.quarkus.io/quarkus-version: 3.12.3
    app.quarkus.io/vcs-uri: https://git...
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: guess-game
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: quarkus
  name: guess-game
  namespace: guess
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: guess-game
                port:
                  name: http
            path: /game(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific

What is the quarkus property to change the spec.rules.http.paths.backend.pathType from Prefix (default) to ImplementationSpecific ?
I've tried to use
quarkus.kubernetes.ingress.rules.1.path=/game(/|$)(.*)
quarkus.kubernetes.ingress.rules.1.path-type=ImplementationSpecific

but it requires to define a host, and I don't want to change host. I'd like to do this on default host.
